# Facing SIGSEGV (segmentation fault) while writing code for Next Largest Number using stack

Tags: c++, stack, c++14

I am getting Segmentation fault on few textcases e.g. (4 3 2 1 ) , wrong and garbage on few. I am not sure what causing this also suggest if there is better and fast way to approach this problem.

```
int nextlargest(int a[],int n)
{
    vector<int> v;
    stack <int> s;
    for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        if(s.size()==0)
         {v.push_back(-1);}
        else if (a[i]<s.top() && s.size()>0) // 4 3 2 1

             v.push_back(s.top());


        else if (s.top()<=a[i] && (s.size()>0))
         {
             while(s.top()<=a[i] && (s.size()>0))
             {
                 s.pop();
                 if(s.size()==0)
                 { v.push_back(-1);}
                 else
                 {v.push_back(s.top());}
             }
         }

         s.push(a[i]);
}
reverse(v.begin(),v.end());
for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++)
cout<<v[i]<<" ";

return 0;

}

int main() {


    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int a[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) cin>>a[i];
    nextlargest(a,n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while(s.top()<=a[i] && (s.size()>0))` It's kind of pointless to check whether the stack is empty **after** you've already accessed `top()` and triggered undefined behavior.

Comment: @S.M. It's true on the first iteration of the loop, but not necessarily on subsequent iterations. There's a `while` loop whose body calls `s.pop()`, then the condition is checked again and calls `s.top()` first thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
    
using namespace std;

void nextLargerElement(int a[], int n)
{
    stack<int>s;
    vector<int>v;
    for(int i=n-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        while(!s.empty() && a[i]>s.top())
            s.pop();
        if(s.empty())
            v.push_back(-1);
        else
            v.push_back(s.top());
        s.push(a[i]);
    }
    reverse(v.begin(), v.end());
    for(int i=0; i<v.size(); i++)
        cout<<v[i]<<" ";
}

int main() 
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int a[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) 
        cin>>a[i];
    nextLargerElement(a,n);
}
```